# could not be realized due to validation errors

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

In Hyper-V when I try to Import Virtual Machine it throw below error:

```
'VM_Name' could not be realized due to validation errors
```

Can you please guide what I should do to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I had this issue... and when I imported the machine, and manually selected where to put the paging file and configuration files, it was using drive letters from the other machine that weren't on the new host.  For instance, the paging files were going into F:\Hyper-V\ , when the new machine didn't have an F: drive.  Its easy to gloss over and miss this.

If this happens, make sure that the drives and directories being filled in for you actually exist..

Comment: We cannot ask the user to create a Volume or in that case even a directory for import to work, What can be done in this case?